# How to pass USB scanned bar code to the window service?

Tags: c#

I am using matrologic USB scanner. Once you scan the barcode, it needs a focused (text field) where it will past the scanned code. I want to capture that scanned code using my window service which will take the code and send it to the database. When record comes back I want to initialize my application for populating the record details.
My client does not want my win form application to be visible on screen until the barcode is scanned and the details are reached.

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems your USB scanner requires a user interface (a text box to put the read barcode in), and you don't want any user interface before the service has done its job with the barcode read. It seems impossible with that scanner.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. A service has no window, you need a window to interact with a HID device like mouse or keyboard.

Take a scanner with uses a serial interface and not a HID one.